# ConEmu new tab instead of split

Tags: windows, command-line, conemu

Is there a way to disable console splitting in ConEmu?

Let's say **I'm in ConEmu window**. I do some stuff and decide to open another cmd tab.

I input `cmd` **inside current ConEmu window**, click enter and new cmd is shown **in the same tab** as split. I've come across `-new_console` switch and that's kinda OK, yet still not good.

If I input `cmd -new_console` **inside current ConEmu window**, it opens in new tab (without split). If I, however, input `csudo cmd -new_console` **inside current ConEmu window**, it still opens as split in the same screen.

So the question is - is there a way to **disable splitting** without any additional text?

ConEmu build 140819 (64-bit).

*What I want to write:* `cmd`

*Expected result:* ConEmu opens completely separate tab without any splits.

**EDIT:** I'm now not able to reproduce cmd splitting - now it opens **in the same tab** without splitting as is expected behaviour of application (noted by Maximus).

But question remains the same anyway. If with `cmd` I can't open a new tab - what about `csudo` or `csudo cmd`? They too open as splits.

Comment: What you write? Where you write? What version is used? Nothing is clear from you question actually.

Comment: Erm... Edited, added version and added more info + formatting. Couldn't think of anything more, because that's all the info and should be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I input cmd inside current ConEmu window, click enter and new cmd is shown in the same tab as split.

But the expected behavior is "second cmd.exe process started in the **same tab** without splitting". So, you need to find what you have changed in your system. Either `Autorun` value in the registry `Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` (HKLM/HKCU), or some alias for `cmd`, or even any batch file, or something else...

You may run Process Monitor to find what is really executed.

**csudo**

`csudo` is expected to open splits. Change the file `csudo.cmd` to change beanie. Thinking it is better to rename your version to avoid changes lost after updating.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really reproduce that simple `cmd` split. Don't know why, it just came back to expected behaviour. Updated the question - maybe there is an answer to that?

Comment: Csudo commented.

Comment: Thank you! I've already been using renamed version to sudo to match Linux. Now changed to not use split - works like I want it.